# Going Through Each Selected Item In *Changing* ListView

Tags: c#, listview, selecteditem

This is the code I use to go through each item in a listView:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listView.SelectedItems.Count; i++) {
    MessageBox.Show(listView.SelectedItems[i].SubItems[0].Text);
}
```

My question is if this will still work if the items in the listView changes.  For instance, let's say I have all of the items in my listView selected, and press a button that runs the code above.  While the code is running, let's say the listView updates, and one of the items is removed.  Will the code still run successfully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a chance that the item is removed just *after* the condition of the loop allowed for another iteration and *before* the item is accessed in the following line.

Given that, this is not what I would call reliable code. You should make sure that the threads do not attempt to access the same resource at the same time, I'd recommend a mutex or using critical sections.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should be using a foreach. However, "successful" iteration depends on your definition. If, during the middle of a foreach iteration, the list is changed, it'll throw an exception. If you use a basic integer index as you already have, no exception will be thrown but the behaviour could be unpredictable. I would use some sort of thread synchronization like a mutex to make sure that you can successfully iterate with a foreach without worrying about the list changing.